# How to perform optimal pattern search between huge json files?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, regex, performance

Looking for solution to perform pattern search  between JSON files which could traverse the huge JSON file without much impact on performance. Following are the few test cases.

#### Search criteria

---

1. 'cabin_1' matches with 'cabin_1'
2. 'cabin_3' matches with 'cabin 3' or '3 cabin'
3. 'first cabin' matches with '1st cabin'

#### Test case files

---

you can find the test json files [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#%2F=undefined&right=local.rihabe&left=cloud.9009e35a7ad84376bd8fe2ce5914e2c5)

#### My Idea

---

```
for each json1Property in json1
     for each json2Property in json2
        isMatch = regex('somepattern', json1property , json2property)
        if (isMatch) 
           return true 
        else 
           return false
```

Comment: You didn't add the JSON files, it is really hard right now to think of a solution without that.
Plus, I think you're not very accurate about what you expect. You only want to get a boolean whether anything matches your matching rules?

Comment: @sjahan json files are there in test case files header. To keep it simple , just matching and returning true or false is suffice here. I am looking for better algorithm rather just looping and comparing each properties

Comment: So you want to compare each `space` to see if they contain matching items, right?
I'm not sure I fully understand your search criteria: are the list exhaustive and explicit?
What is the point of the fifth rule? 'cabin_2' must matches with 'cabin2', but does 'cabin_1' matches with 'cabin1' or only with 'cabin_1'?

Comment: Yes , cabin_1 should match cabin1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather basic and I'm no algorithm expert, but basically, the goal is to build a simple index for each array. You simplify and map values to something more easy/fast to compare later. I think one way or another, you have to iterate on arrays.

Here, you iterate once on each array to build the indices, while in your first attempt, you have a double loop.

The double loop is a bit existing in the second phase, comparing indices with `filter`/`includes` but I think it would be lighter because the arrays' length has decreased and the data is simpler to check.

```js
const data = {
  "Building": {
    "floor": [
      {
        "space": [
          "cabin_1",
          "cabin_2",
          "cabin_3",
          "mycabin"
        ]
      },
      {
        "space": [
          "first cabin",
          "xyz's cabin",
          "Zone c",
          "Zone d"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
const spaces = data.Building.floor;

const indices = spaces.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push(item.space.map(it => {
    return it.replace(/ ?cabin[_ ]?/g, '') //Remove cabin, trailing spaces and underscores.
    .replace(/1st|first/g, '1') //Map things that are not numbers to numbers.
    .replace(/2nd|second/g, '2')
    .replace(/3rd|third/g, '3');
  }).filter(it => !isNaN(it))); //Removes every thing that is not processed by the index engine.
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(indices);

let shorterArray, longerArray;
if(indices[0].length > indices[1].length) {
  shorterArray = indices[1];
  longerArray = indices[0];
} else {
  shorterArray = indices[0];
  longerArray = indices[1];
}

const sharedItems = shorterArray.filter(it => longerArray.includes(it));
console.log('Shared items found', !!sharedItems.length, sharedItems);
```